# Exception is not catched in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, milvus

The following is my class:

```
import {
  Injectable
} from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  MilvusClient
} from '@zilliz/milvus2-sdk-node';

@Injectable()
export class EmbeddingService {
  private client: MilvusClient;

  constructor() {
    try {
      this.client = new MilvusClient('localhost:19530');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to Milvus:', error);
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I stop the milvus service (docker container) the above `new MilvusClient` command raises an error but the error is not catched by the catch block.

I tried to wrap the try-catch inside an IIFE but the same problem and the catch block does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error with the following approach:

```
const milvusClient = new MilvusClient(`invalid-address`);

milvusClient.connectPromise.catch((e)=>{
  console.log('connect failed')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this has nothing to do with nestjs nor nodejs itself, it just how that `MilvusClient` was implemented. Looks like they didn't expose any way to handle errors on the `constructor` method (which is pretty bad)

I'd suggest you to report that in their repository: https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus-sdk-node/issues
`